# Search By Number in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I create the search from table in asp.net mvc , but it is working with the string only, when i change to the int and customer_mobile there some error coming . how i can search by number or int ?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string seraching)
    {
        return View(_context.Customers.Where(x => x.Customer_Name.Contains(seraching) || seraching == null).ToList());
    }
```

view :

```
        @Html.TextBox("seraching")<input type="submit" value="Search" />


@if (Model.Count() == 0)
                    {
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="color:red">
            No Match Any Document
        </td>
    </tr>
                    }

                else
                {

                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
```

Model:

```
public class Customers
{
    [Key]
    public int Customer_Id { get; set; }

    public string Customer_Name { get; set; }

    public int Customer_Mobile { get; set; }
```

Thank you

Comment: in your model, i believe `Customer_Name` is defined as string. Let say you want to search in `Age` , it will be int int

Comment: Why do you want and `int` ? To test against `Customer_Name` or an other field ? In which way ?

Comment: when i change to the int and Chang attribute to mobile number this error coming  Error 2 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Desktop\RES\RES\Controllers\CustomersController.cs 51 55 RES

Comment: you should call this method using jquery than you can get a quick response of list in view.

Comment: How i can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? seraching)
    {
       if (seraching.HasValue){
       return View(_context.Customers.Where(x=>x.Customer_Mobile.ToString().Contains(seraching.ToString())).ToList());}
       else{
       return View(_context.Customers.ToList());}
    }
```

Convert int to string and use contains like you were using.

Comment: this error i get The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'seraching' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'RES.Controllers.CustomersController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Comment: but the if condition is like this  if (seraching.HasValue)
            {

Comment: can change and then i will approve your answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to change the parameter to an int and also change the where clause to search by the attribute that is also an int (for example an Id if it is declared as an int in the Customers model)

Also, you can ditch the .Contains and instead use a simple == operator when comparing integers, therefore resulting in the following:

```
public ActionResult Index(int seraching)
{
    return View(_context.Customers.Where(x => (x.MobileNumber == seraching) || seraching == null).ToList());
}
```

Comment: This erroro come Error 2 'RES.Models.Customers' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\RES\RES\Controllers\CustomersController.cs 53 55 RES

Comment: Updated Answer: If you can give us a better clarification of what you want to search for with this int we can better understand the scenario, and give you tips on how to fix this error. Also, if we know what the model contains we can give you a better answer.

Comment: i add the models .. i want search by the mobile number , but there error , and when i search by name it come

Comment: when searching for a string like Customer_Name you can make use of .Contains but when you want to search by int you cannot make use of .Contains instead you have to use the == operator in the where expression

Comment: Sure: public ActionResult Index(int seraching)
{
    return View(_context.Customers.Where(x => (x.Customer_Mobile== seraching) || seraching == null).ToList());
}

This will search all the Customer_Mobile Numbers

Comment: I get to this error The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'seraching' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'RES.Controllers.CustomersController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Add a '?' to the parameter type to make it nullable (optional). Ex: int? seraching