# How to use seach function by "int" in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: search, asp.net-core-mvc

I use this way add seach function.
But it only can search by string.
I want to add a function of seach by "int".
Anyone have suggest?

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                 select m;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(await movies.ToListAsync());
}
```

And it is my resource
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-5.0
Also I have try like this way,but it seem didn't  work
[Search By Number in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55532528/search-by-number-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search value by `Int` parameter, it is similar like search by string. In the View page, set the element's name attribute as same as the parameter name in the action method.

You can check the following sample:

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Find by name: <input type="text" name="searchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
            Find by ID: <input type="text" name="searchId" value="@ViewData["CurrentID"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            <a asp-action="Index">Back to Full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString, int searchId)
    {
        var students = from stu in _context.Students
                     select stu;
        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        //{
        //    students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString.ToString()));
        //}
        if (searchId !=0)
        {
            students = students.Where(s => s.ID == searchId );
        }
        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
        ViewData["CurrentID"] = searchId;
        return View(await students.ToListAsync()); 
    }
```

Then, the result as below:

[image]

Comment: It is a big help . Thanks!!